# JSCH setCommand is not working

Tags: jsch

No Exception comes and Command is also not making any work based on command mentioned.Here permisson of directory is not created and directory is also not created.Please give your suggestion.

**Update :**
channelexe.getExitStatus is added but problem is it gives -1, what is the meaning of this ?. I don't know how to find some explaination why command is not doing it's job(update 777 mode of **fileDir1**) .

```
        String depDir = "/usr/local/FTPReceive/DEPLOYED/fileDir1";
        log.info("updateDepositedFilePermission ........ starts"); 
        Session session = new FTPComponent().getSession("");
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try
        {
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("session is alive:" + session.isConnected());
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();

            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            ChannelExec channelexe = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channelexe.setCommand("chmod 777 -R " + depDir);                
            channelexe.connect();
            System.out.println("channelexe.getExitStatus:"+channelexe.getExitStatus());
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Manual Exception in updateDepositedFilePermission:" + CommonUtil.getExceptionString(e1));
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
channelexe.setCommand("chmod 777 -R " + depDir);
channelexe.setCommand("mkdir /usr/local/fileStore");
channelexe.connect();
```

A [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) accepts a single command string to invoke on the remote system. Your second call to `setCommand()` is discarding the chmod command and replacing it with the mkdir command. Assuming the remote shell is *bash* or similar, you could use shell syntax to construct a command string which runs both commands:

```
String cmd = "chmod 777 -R " + depDir + " && mkdir /usr/local/fileStore";
channelexe.setCommand(cmd);
```

> No Exception comes...

ChannelExec doesn't throw an exception when a command merely fails. You can call [`Channel.getExitStatus()`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus()) to get the exit status of the remote command. The value will be 0 if `chmod` and `mkdir` succeeded, or non-zero if they failed. The channel also has functions to read the standard error of the remote command, which will permit you to read any error messages which they output.

The JSCH website has several [example programs](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/), including an example of [executing a remote command](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).

Comment: Thanks channelexe.getErrStream() was helpful to get complete trace.